# Return smarty template on json array

Tags: json, jquery, smarty3

How to return Smarty template in json array?
for example:
PHP:

```
$smarty=new Smarty();  
....  
$title='some text';  
echo json_encode(array('title'=>$title,'page'=>$smarty->display('templatename.tpl')));
```

jQuery:

```
$.post('pages.php',{id:id,page:page},function(json){
    $('.title').text(json.title);
    $('.content').html(json.page);
},'json');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty's [display()](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.display.tpl) echos the rendered template to the outbut buffer. You're probably looking for [fetch()](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.fetch.tpl) to get the rendered template as string.

```
<?php
// …
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo json_encode(array(
  'title' => $title,
  'page' => $smarty->fetch('templatename.tpl'),
));
```